# Copying Artifact from local Maven repository to remote

Tags: maven

I am trying to implement a staged CI/CD pipeline with a Gradle library. I have managed to get Gradle publishing the produced library to a local Maven repository (build/repository). What I'd like to do then is manually 'promote' the artifact in this local repository to a remote one. A different remote one for each stage in the build pipeline.

And I don't want that logic to be part of Gradle. What I'd like is a way to simply run a Maven command (mvn) to copy the artifact in build/repository to http://myrepositoryurl. I've found Maven copy:stage. However, it fails with some exception about missing implementation for `org.apache.maven.plugins.stage.RepositoryCopier`.

Problem is I know nothing about Maven, and don't know what this means. It recognizes 'copy', as it is trying to Do Something, and has figured out that RepositoryCopier at least is the thing it needs. But it won't work.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: this mixture is all a bit weird? is maven or gradle your main build system? The "simple" maven command to copy a file to the remote repository is probably in the deploy plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/plugin-info.html - requires quite some parameters if used on the command line but should do the trick.

Comment: Why are you trying to do a staging manually? Alle repository manager support that (most of them only the commercial ones) apart from that usually there is no advantage about using a staging ....

Comment: I'm trying to deploy a package without the source code that built the package. So, Gradle is gone. I'd like to have the build (with Gradle) produce "something", that I can then later deploy.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not Maven command to copy from a local repository to a remote one.

Maven deploys files from the `target` directory to remote repositories.